# My polygon layer doesnt show after changing symbology

Tags: qgis, polygon, style

When I changed my polygon symbology in properties section from "single symbol to graduated", my shape file has been disappeared. I changed the CRS but still it didn't work. Can anyone knows the reason

[image]

Comment: What is the existing CRS?

Comment: Its EPSG 4326: WGS 84

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it disappears. You must define a value for the source of the graduated style ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?#graduated-renderer)): based on the values of which attribute should the style be graduated? Choose the appropriate field and the shape will appear again.

*Select the value (here: the attribute `val`), than click `Classify`. You might choose the mode how the graduation should be applied as well as the number of classes:*
[image]

Comment: -Babel Its work.. Thank You so much